# Create lists to projects/repos in group and subgroup?

Tags: gitlab

I have this workgroup and **I would like to make lists of interesting projects/repos contained in different subgroups.** This would make it easier for us to find relevant projects.

I know you can share a project with a group if you are the owner of that project but **can I, as maintainer of a group, add links to public projects without the owner of that project having to do anything?**

Another option for me could be to just do a readme file with links but then I could get dead links and I would miss the project description and most importantly, when they last was updated.

Answer (score 0):

This does not 100% qualifies as an answer, as i see it as a hack or misuse of a feature of GitLab. But i thought the idea is worth sharing. Additionally it will only work with projects which you can actively change - else this would need interaction of project maintainer.

GitLab supports optional topics on projects, they can be maintained by maintainers within the general settings of a project.

[image: General Settings]

If you add a topic `interesting`. they get searchable by this tag like https://gitlab.com/explore/projects?tag=interesting

This way, you can create and maintain a list, which is always up to date and show the most recent description, name, etc. - also in connection with permissions (you will not see something you are not suppose to see).

The downside is, that this topic might not be suitable to be (ab-)used within your group, and it might add more confusion for others than it should, because you will see this topic in the project overview page.

[image: Project overview page]